# setOnClickListener for custom listview item doesn't work on android 1.5

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I know that there are a lot of similar questions, but I didn't find still a working solution for me. I have a listview layout similar to this one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and in my listview adapter I have the next `getView` method:

```
@Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

            if (convertView == null) {

                mHolder = new Holder();
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_1, null);
                mHolder.firstLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
                mHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

                convertView.setTag(mHolder);
            }

            mHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
            mHolder.text1.setText("text");


            mHolder.firstLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    android.util.Log.e("TAG", "mHolder.firstLayout   onClick");
                }
            });

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    android.util.Log.e("TAG", "convertView  onClick");
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }
```

`mHolder.firstLayout.setOnClickListener` and `convertView.setOnClickListener` don't work, but:

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        android.util.Log.e("TAG", "mListView  onClick");

    }
});
```

it works, but I need exactly listeners for my listview items.

I know that problem is with focus, because using `requestFocus()` listeners inside getView work, but it's not a good solution.

```
It works good for 2.3 but doesn't work for 1.5, I need to get it working exactly for 1.5
```

Comment: Why do you want to set the click on your listview items? Can you just do the same with onItemClickListener? One of the parameters is the view, so I can't see the problem. Any other way, set the listview items as clickable.

Comment: because I have a complex listview item, I can not do it with onItemClickListener

Comment: just do view.getHolder()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**There is no reason for setting listeners for each item of the in your getView().**

It may create more problem. Keep things simple and set a `Listener just for the ListView in your onCreate()`

Change your `getView()`:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (convertView == null) {

            mHolder = new Holder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_1, null);
            mHolder.firstLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
            mHolder.text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);

            convertView.setTag(mHolder);
        }

        mHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        mHolder.text1.setText("text");


        return convertView;
    }
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I have a complex listview item, the above is just a test sample to show that inside getView listeners for custom views don't work.